# IIS 8.5 400 Bad Request

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, iis-8

I've some difficulties with an ASP.Net Core Web Api Application which is hosted on an IIS 8.5.
The IIS 8.5 returns a 400 status code for a specific post request.

The faulty request is executed by an web application which is hosted on the same domain with a different port. The API is configured to handle cors and the preflight of the faulty request is successfully completed.

I noticed a weird thing:
The Api is deployed with Swagger UI included. So I tried to reproduce the error with the Swagger UI. But in this case the request is successful.
The body and the url of both requests are absolutely the same and there are no noticeable differences in the headers except, of course, of the request origin.

It looks like the request is not processed by the Api at all (I should see sth. in our log files in this case), so I'm pretty sure the error occurs somewhere in the IIS itself.

I've already investigated the httperr.log file. It contains the flowing line at the time of the failed request:

> 2018-12-05 15:38:36 192.168.100.132 62121 192.168.100.173 1142
>   HTTP/1.1 POST /api/some/request/path 400 13 BadRequest myServicePool

I was hoping this file would contain more details about the cause of the error.
I was wondering if the "13" before  "BadRequest" has any special meaning?

Does anyone have an idea, based on the information given, why this error occurs? I don't really think so. But I would be more than happy if anybody can give me a hint where to search for more details about the cause of the error.
Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: 13 is probably the sc-win32-status (-> your header in log file)

Comment: or HTTP sub status... the IIS log contains only some basic information about the traffic, not what's going on inside the IIS, what does the eventlog state what is happening? you can also try to enable the failedrequest tracing, which provides some comprehensive details of the IIS pipeline, especially when you guess, the POST is not reaching the app.

Comment: HTTP error log won't be able to give you more hints. But you can capture the problematic HTTP request in tools like Wireshark, and analyze its details against HTTP RFC documents. Note that such should be done at byte level in most cases, than merely strings.

Comment: It doesn't look like 13 is the sub status. At least it is not listed as possible sub status in the microsoft documentation: https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Answer (score 0):

It's better if we can have sample code of how you are sending the request in your code.

However, with the given facts I assume the problem is in the content of the request body. Even the swagger request and the request you are sending look like exactly the same, it should be varying in some aspects.

Are you using a JSON converter? If you are using a JSON converter and if you are serializing a .NET model to a JSON string and attaching in the request please make sure that you are formatting it with **Camel Case**.

Because by default it might just be converting the .NET model as it is with the Pascal case.

**EXAMPLE**

I'll elaborate this using **Newtonsoft JSON** library.

.NET model serialized without specifying the format

```
var businessLeadJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ObjectA);
```

Converted result -  `{"Company":"sample","ContactName":"contact 1"}`

.NET model serialized by specifying the format

```
var businessLeadJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(businessLead, new 
      JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
```

Converted result - `{"company":"sample","contactName":"contact 1"}`

**Please notice the case of the property names in JSON strings. The first letter is capital in the first result.**

Therefore I recommend you to try serializing your objects that are attaching as the payload (request body) **by specifying the formatting**, becasue REST APIs expect the JSON strings in the correct format.

**Please specify the Camel case formatting when you are serializing the object of your request body.**

Good Luck..!

Comment: HTTP error log is written by HTTP.sys, so such 400 means a basic HTTP protocol violation, than JSON level violation.

Comment: The request is made by a javascript application. I've used plain javascript objects as request body. So I'm sure the problem does not lie within the json body.
I can't even reproduce the problem on our development system, it only occurs on the production system of our customer.

Answer (score 0):

I've justed managed to reproduce this error by accident.

The problem is, that the application send an empty Authorization-Header if the user hasn't login yet.

It seems that causes an Bad Request on some configurations/IIS versions, or what ever the difference is between the systems,and on some it's no problem.